# Recursion function for prime number check

Tags: python, recursion, primes

I have this code:

```py
def has_divisors(n, i=2):
    """
    Check if a number is prime or not
    :param n: Number to check
    :param i: Increasing value that tries to divide
    :return: True if prime, False if not
    """
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if i + 1 == n:
        return True
    if n <= 2 and n > 0:
        return True
    if n % i == 0:
        return False
    return has_divisors(n, i + 1)
```

Which tell if a number is prime or not, problem is that it can check if a number is prime up to +- 1500 after that it enters into maximum recursion depth error. Does anyone has any idea how to make this code more efficient and get to higher numbers (I don't want a completely different code if possible, yes I know recursion is not a good idea for this function but I have to use it) Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain, or expand upon, what exactly the reason is for a recursive method to be required?  Does it have to use this exact function signature?  Can a recursive helper function be used instead?  I ask because testing `997` results in close to one thousand redundant checks of `n <= 1`, `n <= 2`, and `n > 0`.  With a better understanding of the exact constraints, more efficient solutions will be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python and recursion are not a good mix, because Python doesn't do tail call optimization.  (There's a fun blog post here that explores a cheesy workaround that you probably don't want to do for this project: https://chrispenner.ca/posts/python-tail-recursion)

Leaving that aside, there are two opportunities I see for optimization:

```
if i + 1 == n:
    return True
```

The largest minimum factor of any given number is going to be its square root, so you don't need to look for factors all the way up to `n`.

```
return has_divisors(n, i + 1)
```

If `n` wasn't divisible by 2, it's not going to be divisible by any other even number, so this recursive call is a waste of time (and stack space) at least half the time.  Are there any other ways you might be able to know before you recurse that a given new value of `i` isn't going to be fruitful?

Comment: Recursion is always suboptimal. Not just in Python...

Comment: @slepic That's a bold claim.

Comment: @AMC prove me wrong.

Comment: Long before computers were even dreamt of, mathematicians were looking for ways of expressing recursive problems without recursion. For Fun? No! Because they knew there Is an inherent complexity in the recursion.

Comment: @slepic Somehow I missed the _Not just in Python_ part. That's not even bold, just silly.

Comment: Let the man enjoy his kool-aid.

Comment: @AMC I believe what I said is true. But i don't know how to prove it. Feel free to disagree. But this is just word against word. Words like bold and silly have no value to the conversation. But it should be easy for you to disprove my claim then by showing one counter example (if we can even settle on what that claim means). Until you do, good bye.

Comment: @SamStafford What kool-aid?

Comment: @slepic _one counter example_ An example where recursion isn't suboptimal? How about tree/graph data structures? What about all the programming languages which make heavy use of recursion, like Haskell, Lisp, etc? Recursion isn't particularly complicated, it's purely a matter of habit.

Comment: Okay, look.  With a decent compiler/interpreter, equivalent recursive/iterative constructs boil down to the same machine instructions, so the efficiency argument goes out the window, which leaves you with "what's easier for a human reader to understand?"  And that's something that you can probably make an argument for being generally more intuitive one way or the other in a broad set of circumstances, but  if someone is enough of a zealot to even attempt the argument that doing it one particular way is easier for 100% of people 100% of the time, it's not worth arguing.  Just nod and smile.

Comment: @SamStafford If it boiled down to the same machine code, it means the optimizer was smart enough to get rid of the recursion. The machine code is no longer recursive (unless you wanna claim that every for/while/goto is in fact also recursion) and that only confirms my claim. I didn't wanna argue about readability. In fact, I am on the side which thinks that recursively written algorithm is easier to understand. Not in 100% cases and not for 100% people though.

Comment: @AMC It would be hard for me to disprove this for every graph/tree algorithm. Give me a specific one (ideally implemented the recursive version) and I'll try to provide non recursive version which will be less suboptimal. As for Haskell and such, I never said the better solution must exist within the same programming language. It may be that in haskell (some) recursive algorithms cannot be written more performant without recursion. But I believe it may be written less suboptimal in some other language. It may be utterly more complicated to write though. But thats not what I was agruing about.

Comment: @AMC It may also be that the nonrecursive is faster, but just not so much to be worth it. Maybe this is the case for some graph/tree algorithms... If I said "For every recursive algorithm there is a nonrecurisve version which is equaly good or better", would that be more appealing to you?

Comment: *nods and smiles*

Comment: _If I said "For every recursive algorithm there is a nonrecurisve version which is equaly good or better", would that be more appealing to you?_ No, that's still an **incredibly broad** statement ;) I'm not particularly interested in debating the specifics of the issue, especially in the comments of an answer on Code Review, I just wanted to interrupt the anti-recursion circlejerk...

Answer (score 1):

Basically your function boils down to.

```
def has_div(n,i=2):
    return n>1 and (i*i>n or (n%i!=0 and has_div(n,i+1)))
```

which is the same as

```
def has_div2(n,i=2):
    if n<=1:
           return False
    if i*i > n :
           return True
    if n%i == 0:
           return False
    return has_div2(n,i+1)
```

The two functions work for 997991 and report recursion depth exceeded for 998009 which are 78359th and 78360th prime numbers.